# SWT browser java script issue with window.external

Tags: java, javascript, swt

I'm trying to launch another application with in my SWT 4.3 browser. But the java script which is embedded in the called application has a reference to 'window.external' which is causing application not launching with a java script error.
Can any one suggest?

Comment: At the line - " window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm " it is showing error " Object doesn't support this property or method "

Comment: Is the SWT browser using IE (AutoCompleteSaveForm only works on IE).

Comment: How can verify my SWT browser is using IE or some other?

Comment: If you have not specified SWT.MOZILLA or SWT.WEBKIT as the `Browser` style then on Windows it will use IE.